# Select запрос на неповторяющиеся пары

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-server

Есть таблица, состоящая из 1 столбца `id` и 9 строк `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9`.

Нужно соорудить такой select-запрос, чтобы в конечном итоге остались только эти пары (2 столбца):

`(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (1, 7), (1, 8), (1, 9)`

`(2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (2, 7), (2, 8), (2, 9)`

`(3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6), (3, 7), (3, 8), (3, 9)`

`(4, 5), (4, 6), (4, 7), (4, 8), (4, 9)`

`(5, 6), (5, 7), (5, 8), (5, 9)`

`(6, 7), (6, 8), (6, 9)`

`(7, 8), (6, 9)`

`(8, 9)`.

Кроме кросс джойна и множества подзапросов идей нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from [dbo].[t] t left join [dbo].[t] t1 on t.id<t1.id
```

Comment: select * from [dbo].[t] t left join [dbo].[t] t1 on t.id<t1.id

Comment: Спасибо, только лучше без left. Там с null появляется.